# Convert List<Map> to other List<Map> with some keys from first List, plus entire first list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` containing the following data, shown as json for readability:

```
data1 = [ {
    "siteId" : 1,
    "siteName" : "Site 1",
    "member" : "John Doe",
    "age" : 20
}, {
    "siteId" : 1,
    "siteName" : "Site 1",
    "member" : "James Doe",
    "age" : 30
}, {
    "siteId" : 2,
    "siteName" : "Site 2",
    "member" : "Jane Doe",
    "age" : 40
}, {
    "siteId" : 2,
    "siteName" : "Site 2",
    "member" : "Judy Doe",
    "age" : 50
} /* etc ... */ ]
```

I need to convert it into this:

```
data2 = [ {
    "siteId" : 1,
    "siteName" : "Site 1",
    "values" : [ {
        "siteId" : 1,
        "siteName" : "Site 1",
        "member" : "John Doe",
        "age" : 20
    }, {
        "siteId" : 1,
        "siteName" : "Site 1",
        "member" : "James Doe",
        "age" : 30
    } ]
}, {
    "siteId" : 2,
    "siteName" : "Site 2",
    "values" : [ {
        "siteId" : 2,
        "siteName" : "Site 2",
        "member" : "Jane Doe",
        "age" : 40
    }, {
        "siteId" : 2,
        "siteName" : "Site 2",
        "member" : "Judy Doe",
        "age" : 50
    } ]
} ]
```

How can that be done in an efficient (Java8-ish) way avoiding several nested loops?

**Edit**

This is the best I came up with so far:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data1 = service.getData1();
List<Map<String, Object>> data2 = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Object> t2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

data1.forEach(item -> {
    String id = (String) item.get("siteId");
    if (!t2.containsKey(id)) {
        t2.put(id, item.get("siteName"));
    }
});

t2.forEach((k, v) -> {
    Map<String, Object> t3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    t3.put("siteId", k);
    t3.put("siteName", v);
    t3.put("values", r.stream().filter(line -> ((String) line.get("siteId")).equals(k)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    data2.add(t3);
});
```

**Edit 2**

After consulting [Maurice Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7036419/maurice-perry)'s answer, this turned out to be the best solution:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> transformListToGrouped2(final List<Map<String, Object>> r, final String key1, final String key2) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Map<String, Object>> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> prev = null;
    for (final Map<String, Object> cur : r) {
        if (prev == null || !prev.get(key1).equals(cur.get(key1))) {
            final Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
            values = new ArrayList<>();
            obj.put(key1, cur.get(key1));
            obj.put(key2, cur.get(key2));
            obj.put("values", values);
            data2.add(obj);
        }
        values.add(cur);
        prev = cur;
    }
    return data2;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered actually using JSON, it would be a lot easier to use than what you're currently using. If you don't want to use JSON could you at least tell us what format you want your data "converted" into?

Comment: Can you add the whole class declaration you have and the class you wanted to converted into? In JAVA code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> values = null;
Map<String, Object> prev = null;
for (Map<String, Object> cur: data1) {
    if (prev == null || !prev.get("siteId").equals(cur.get("siteId"))) {
        Map<String,Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
        values = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.put("siteId", cur.get("siteId"));
        obj.put("siteName", cur.get("siteName"));
        obj.put("values", values);
        data2.add(obj);
    }
    values.add(cur);
    prev = cur;
}
```

Comment: It does. As a plus it keeps the right order of sites and people.

Answer (score 0):

Below is more Java-8 way to try for -

```
class SiteInfo {
  int siteId
  String siteName
}

class VisitInfo {
  int siteId
  String siteName
  String member
  int age

  getSiteInfo {
   return new SiteInfo(siteId, siteName)
  }
}

class GroupedVisitInfo {
  int siteId
  String siteName
  List[VisitInfo] userVisits
}


// code

Map <SiteInfo, List<VisitInfo>> groupedVisitInfo = userVisitdata.stream().collect(groupingBy(VisitInfo::getSiteInfo));
```

Try it and let me know your opinion.